# Problem doing pagination with sorting on field mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I have a collection for which i want to make queries with pagination by sorting it with dateCreated field as decending to get latest documents.

Am holding `lastKnownCommentId`(Object id) for performance purpose. Having `lastKnownCommentId` would avoid loading documents from starting again during next paginations, if not then applying `limit` on query will cause performance issue.

```
Query<Comment> query = datastore.createQuery(Comment.class)
                .field(POST_ID).equal(postId);
        if (lastKnownCommentId != null) {
            query.field(FieldConstants.OBJECT_ID).greaterThan(new ObjectId(lastKnownCommentId));
        }
        query.order(Sort.descending(FieldConstants.DATE_CREATED));
        return query.asList(new FindOptions().limit(10));
```

Now i have 12 documents in this collection which matches to one `postId`. When this query is excecuted for first pagination with `lastKnownCommentId=null` it gives me 10 documents sorted by date, 2 documents are still not in pagination picture.

For second pagination with `lastKnownCommentId=someId` (someId is object id of last document obtained from first pagination), it gives me again 9 documents as result instead of 2 documents which remained in first pagination.

Things are working fine if i dont do sorting by date, i can completely skip this sorting and do sorting on array list instead. Am not understanding why this happening with sorting in query.

I tried to cross check with aggregation and results same ouput.

```
    db.comment.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
            "postId":{"$eq":"5fb2090fe4d37312a4c3ce59"}
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $sort: {
            "dateCreated":-1
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
            "_id":{"$gt":ObjectId("5fb0e53392ad724f9026d2f7")}
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $limit:  // positive integer
             10
        },
    ],

    // Options
    {
        cursor: {
            batchSize: 50
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `query` look like just before you return it? (print out the value, or do a for loop if it's an object so you can see what the values are).

Comment: It exactly same as i have aggregation query in my question. I made a aggregation query to cross check what result am getting in every stage. Combined result of all stages gives me same result as normal query. I see that sorting with dateCreated is troubling here.